# Monotouch Using NSData.FromBytes

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios

I have a **byte[]** that holds an image (from a database)

I am trying to get NSData using **NSData.FromBytes(IntPtr,uint)**

How do I pass my **byte[]** into that?

This fails of course:

```
UIImage i = 
    UIImage.LoadFromData (NSData.FromBytes (item.Picture, item.Picture.Length));
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
UIImage i = 
UIImage.LoadFromData (NSData.FromArray(myByteArray));
```